# How to compare the user defined string object using patter.matcher inside the hashmap iterator

Tags: java, regex, hashmap

I have to match the given `string Object` with the `hash map key value`.Where `key value as Regex`.
How to get the compiled pattern of `regex`and how to match this with the user defined string.

Please help me.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please give example input and example output.

Comment: Regexes   (   Clint is a hard worker   ,Peter is a smart worker ,Clint and Peter are smart worker ) and its correspoding values are (    ABC , DEF ,  EFG )                    

I have table looks like above and I have to fetch those values and put it in a Hashmap Where Regex as key User defined String input like 'PETER IS A SMART WORKER' .While iterating the Hashmap I have to check with the input String with Key (Regex) of Hashmap.If it matches I have get the correspoding Value.

I hope you clear,

Thank you

Comment: No, it's not clear at all. Edit your question.

Comment: @JB Nizet .There are some regexes are predefined and stored it in a Database table calles RegexExTable.In the table , For Each Regex one matching value is availabe that is Called XYZ.In my java program I have to validate the user input string and to get the XYZ value.So I am going to put the RegexTable Values into Hashmap where Regex as Key.While Iterating the Hashmap I have to check the each key value with the Input string using Regex pattern and matcher method.If any of the key value matches , I have to get the corresponding XYZ value .

Comment: OK. So what is the problem? You simply need to iterate over the entries of the map, test if the regexp of the entry matches with the input, and return the value if it does.

Comment: Yes please .Since I am new to java .I dont know how to use the compiled form of Regex to compare with the input string inside the hashmap itereator.  If you have any exapmles of that please share it .It will helpful for me.

Comment: Read the answer from @fge. Read the javadoc of the classes involved.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Pattern.compile(s)` to obtain a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) out of a `String` `s`.

Use `p.matcher(s)` to obtain a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) out of a `Pattern` `p` on a `String` `s`.

Then you can use the `Matcher`.

Note that ideally you should store `Pattern`s as keys in your `Map`; creating the same set of patterns each time is a waste.

Comment: Hi Fge  ,Thank you for the reply .I have a questions on your reply .                     1. What is the need for pattern.compile of the input string .               2.In my understanding the compile is needed only for regex ,corrct me if am wrong

Comment: The need is simple: not to recompile a pattern each time.

Comment: can you please explain indetail. I got confused .Your help is highly appreciated .please